# contenteditable single-line showing all the characters using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to truncate the characters if user focus the div it shows all the characters without truncating .

We archived the same , but we got multiple lines

but i need user focus the div  need to ***show all the characters in single line*** .

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/L304y4ua/1/)

**HTML:**

This should worksThis should works    This should worksThis should worksThis should worksThis should worksThis should worksThis should worksThis should worksThis should worksThis should worksThis should works

**CSS:**

```
 .single-line {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

    [contenteditable="true"].single-line {
        white-space: nowrap;
        width:200px;
        overflow: hidden;
    } 
    [contenteditable="true"].single-line br {
        display:none;

    }
    [contenteditable="true"].single-line * {
        display:inline;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }


 .single-line:focus {
    white-space:normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this ?

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L304y4ua/6/)

I add a fixed `height` on the container and disable the `text-overflow` property on focus.

```
.single-line:focus {
   text-overflow: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update the `width` to `auto` like this:

```
.single-line:focus {
   width: auto;
}
```

Check the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/heshamElghndour/L304y4ua/9/)

Comment: :we no need to increase width . how to archive that

Comment: I figured it out by adding span.space and give it the extra width you want to add like this:
 .space{
   width: 50px;
   display: inline-block !important;
 }
Check it here https://jsfiddle.net/L304y4ua/10/

Answer (score 0):

Make this change in the :foucs css.

```
.single-line:focus {
    white-space:normal;
    width:100%; //change
}
```

Comment: we no need to increase width . how to archive that